# Why does cat change the contents of binary files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cat

Apparently, running `cat` on a binary file and echoing back the contents doesn't seem to be working. Here is the simple script I made:

```
#!/bin/sh

CONTENTS=$(cat "$1")
mv "$2" "$1"
echo "$CONTENTS" > "$2"
```

For some reason, this seems to be messing up when I do things like this:

```
script first.pptx second.pptx
```

After running this, the new `first.pptx` file opens fine, but the new `second.pptx` file is supposedly in an invalid format or something.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: don't use variables to store intermediate values? `mv $1 tmp; mv $2 $1; mv tmp $2`? Good luck.

Comment: @shelter Would it be possible to do that without creating a temporary file?

Comment: Huh? Why would it be a problem with `cat`, rather than a problem with storing arbitrary content in a C-style string (which is, by its nature, NUL-terminated and thus unable to store literal NULs)?

Comment: BTW, you *can* store contents with literal NULs inside shell **arrays**, just not scalar values.

Comment: ...witness answer posted with demonstration of same. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct `$(cat "$1")` will strip off any trailing newlines in the file before substituting the value (so that's what `CONTENTS` will end up with).

`echo "$CONTENTS"` will truncate the contents at the first NUL character, and append a newline.

So if if the file doesn't end with exactly one newline, the contents will be changed slightly.  If it has any NUL characters, it will be truncated.

Comment: It's not the `echo` that will truncate the contents at the first NUL -- that happens earlier, since contents with literal NULs can't be stored in shell variables (those being C strings) at all.

Comment: ...also, if you read the POSIX spec for `echo`, behavior when passed a string with any backslashes is completely undefined. Even if we ignored the trailing newline, it's a tool utterly unsuited for binary data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's proof that `cat` *does not* change the contents of values, and that the script you're trying to implement, while having no practical value, actually *can* be written in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=( )
{
    while IFS= read -r -d '' s; do
        arr+=( "$s" )
    done
    arr+=( "$s" )
} < <(cat "$1")  ## aside: this would be more efficiently just <"$1" without the cat

mv "$2" "$1"

{
    printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]:0:${#arr[@]}-1}"
    printf '%s' "${arr[@]:${#arr[@]}-1}"
} >"$2"
```

---

Now, how does this work?

- `arr` is a shell array; each element is a C string.
- `while IFS= read -r -d '' s` reads NUL-delimited strings from the input file into `s`, incrementally. It only returns true while those strings are NUL-terminated; when a string exists without a NUL terminator, the variable `s` is still populated, but the `read` command returns false. [See [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more on the `while read` idiom].
- ...thus, the last element of the array includes content *after* the final NUL.
- `printf '%s\0' ...` emits each argument after the format string (in the `...` area) followed by a NUL delimiter. `${#arr[@]}` expands to the number of entries in the array `arr`, and `${arrayname[@]:SEEK:COUNT}` expands to `COUNT` items from the array `arrayname` after skipping the first `SEEK` items; thus, `${arr[@]:0:${#arr[@]}-1}` expands to all but the last item from the array `arr`, printing these each followed by a NUL.
- The final `printf` emits that trailing content -- from the very last array entry -- after the final NUL.

---

If running this, you will observe that the md5sums of the input files swap, even when they are binary files containing NUL values. Thus, the premise of your question is false: `cat` **does not** change the contents of binary files.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the same but with temp file.

```
cat < $file1 > $tempFile
cat < $file2 > $file1
cat < $tempFile > $file2
rm $tempFile
```